# One liner Python equivalent of JavaScript like assignment when value is falsey

Tags: javascript, python

Consider a function in JavaScript:
If `val` is not defined in the first call, it becomes `0`

```
function someRecursiveFn (item, val) {
    val = val || 0;
    ...
}
```

How do I assign the same way in Python?

```
def someRecursiveFn(item, val):
    val = ??
    ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Assign Value if None Exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338501/python-assign-value-if-none-exists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a keyword argument instead of a plain argument to your function:

```
def someRecursiveFn(item, val=None):
    val = val or 0
```

so `val` will default to `None` if it's not passed to the function call.

the `val = val or 0` will ensure that `val=None` or `val=''` are converted to 0. Can be omitted if you only care about `val` being defined in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

`val = val if val else 0`

`#if val is not None, it will assign itself, if it is None it will set val=0`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
def someRecursiveFn(item, val):
    val = val if val else 0
```

But the python idiom `if val` is quite broad as it can have different meanings, some of them could even mean something in a specific context(for example the `0` value), contrarily to an `undefined` value in javascript.

In python, all the following are considered **false**:

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
- any empty mapping, for example, {}.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False